# US Radiation measurements

Tags: data-request, usa, data.gov, government, environment

Is there a service that provides gamma energy data from [RadNet](https://www.epa.gov/radnet/near-real-time-and-laboratory-data-state) in machine readable format such as JSON or CSV?

The current RadNet UI is restricted to html and charts. Excel report itself is limited to 400 samples.

Likewise, EPA sources on [data.gov](https://catalog.data.gov/dataset?q=radnet&as_sfid=AAAAAAWOlPRVE-S3l9gKNeDYI1CNId6htO2Oe5dhGmTom-PnNIIBgvUCktgSIGAdULbl2Eqzuu2e7-eB7vYSnxRlk89Tb41w3lRST6hcYoEz0FaZMmm9PWBOSEmWXRU4eIAl3T0%3D&as_fid=8fbb29ecbce53a7fbc2fddf19ec7fa7a077c0626) contain no time-series data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since January 18, 2018, near-real-time data are available for download on [this page](https://www.epa.gov/radnet/radnet-csv-file-downloads) in CSV format.

I suppose [this FAQ answer](https://radiation.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000091092-How-often-are-RadNet-s-near-real-time-air-monitoring-data-updated-on-the-EPA-website-) is applicable to CSV files too:

> RadNet near-real-time air data are refreshed hourly during business
>   hours, Monday through Friday. This hourly refresh ensures that the
>   most up-to-date data are available for the last 24 hours.